# Переключение в карточке товара WooCommerce связанных атрибутов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть вариативный товар. У него два атрибута: цвет и размер. Товар с цветом 1 существует только в размере 1. Аналогично, цвет 2 только с размером 2.
Задача сделать так, чтобы при выборе размера 1 в карточке товара автоматически выбирался и цвет 1. Ну цвет 1 переключал размер 1 соответственно.
Сейчас же при выборе цвета размер, который ему не соответствует, просто недоступен для выбора. А это визуально неочевидно. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] То есть если из положения на картинке выбрать другой размер, которого нет для выбранного ниже бежевого, то просто обнулится выбор размера, никакой не будет выбран. А нужно, чтобы цвет переключился на черный, потому что размер 17*24 как раз черный.

Comment: Может проще сделать, чтобы было очевидно? Например затенять/скрывать/блокировать недоступный для выбора атрибут. Собственно, по умолчанию так и есть, но судя по скринам это поведение изменяет какой-то плагин.